# My app can't find my TypeScript package downloaded from the NPM registry (module not found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm having problems packaging [my TypeScript project](https://github.com/tobier/robotnik) that I've published on the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotnik-bot). I'm new to packaging modules for others to use so I'm probably just doing something wrong.

These are the parts of the [package.json](https://github.com/tobier/robotnik/blob/master/package.json) that seems relevant:

```
{
  "name": "robotnik-bot",
  "version": "0.1.0-4",
  "description": "Friendly neighborhood Discord bot",
  "main": "out/index",
  "types": "out/index.d.ts",
  "typings:": "out/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register tests/**/*.test.ts",
    "coverage": "nyc -r lcov -e .ts -x \"*.test.ts\" npm run test",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "prepublish": "tsc"
  },
```

And this is the [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/tobier/robotnik/blob/master/tsconfig.json):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "outDir": "out",
      "sourceRoot" : "src",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
      ]
    },
    "exclude": [
      "out",
      "nodule_modules",
      "tests"
    ],
    "lib": ["es2015"],
  }
```

In my dependent project I have added the package as a dependency and try to use it:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "robotnik-bot": "^0.1.0-4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.8.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start" : "tsc && node dist/index.js"
  }
```

```js
import { Builder } from 'robotnik-bot';

const bot = new Builder().build();
```

But the dependent project can't find the module. When I check `nodue_modules` it seems to have just packaged my project file structure with the TypeScript sources; shouldn't there be some compiled Javascript?

Comment: (There's an extra `:` after `typings` that should probably be removed: "typings:": "out/index.d.ts",`)

Comment: Also, your `main` should probably point to `out/index.js`, not just `index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be compiled files. If there are not, you either published a clean working directory (without the compiled files) or your packaging is configured to not include the compiled files.

You can use `npm publish --dry-run` to see what will be included.

Note the following [from the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish):

> Publishes a package to the registry so that it can be installed by name. All files in the package directory are included if no local `.gitignore` or `.npmignore` file exists. If both files exist and a file is ignored by `.gitignore` but not by `.npmignore` then it will be included

Your files seem to be excluded via `.gitignore` which makes sense. You can add them back using the `files` property in the `package.json`, e.g.

```
"files": [
    "out"
]
```

Comment: I will try this, thanks. What would be reasonable to ignore with .npmignore? I'm thinking the package should only include: the compiled files, typings, README and LICENSE.

Comment: That is probably a bit down to preference and what the compiled output looks like. One might e.g. include sources and source maps, which would help in finding an issue if there is a bug in your code and the compiled code is minified. I don't like to use `.npmignore` because it tends to duplicate most of the `.gitignore` anyway, so just adding back what you need via `files` seems less redundant.